# Can't get text to wrap around image

Tags: images, text

I'm trying to get the text to wrap around my image on my about page here

http://www.biggerplay.com/about

But as you can see the text just sits at the bottom of the image, how can I make it wrap around the image and be up top at the start of the image to the right of the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress provides a few generated classes just for this issue.  What you probably want is to float the image left in your example.

The CSS rules listed in the Generated Classes section of this Codex page are what you are after.
https://codex.wordpress.org/CSS#WordPress_Generated_Classes

For the sake of future-proofing or a URL change, here is that content:

**WordPress Generated Classes**

Several classes for aligning images and block elements (div, p, table etc.) were introduced in WordPress 2.5: aligncenter, alignleft and alignright. In addition the class alignnone is added to images that are not aligned, so they can be styled differently if needed.

The same classes are used to align images that have a caption (as of WordPress 2.6). Three additional CSS classes are needed for the captions, and one more for accessibility. Together, the classes are:

```
/* =WordPress Core
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
.alignnone {
    margin: 5px 20px 20px 0;
} 

.aligncenter,
div.aligncenter {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px auto 5px auto;
}

.alignright {
  float:right;
  margin: 5px 0 20px 20px;
}

.alignleft {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 20px 20px 0;
}

a img.alignright {
  float: right;
  margin: 5px 0 20px 20px;
}

a img.alignnone {
  margin: 5px 20px 20px 0;
}

a img.alignleft {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 20px 20px 0;
}

a img.aligncenter {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto
}

.wp-caption {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
  max-width: 96%; /* Image does not overflow the content area */
  padding: 5px 3px 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.wp-caption.alignnone {
  margin: 5px 20px 20px 0;
}

.wp-caption.alignleft {
  margin: 5px 20px 20px 0;
}

.wp-caption.alignright {
  margin: 5px 0 20px 20px;
}

.wp-caption img {
  border: 0 none;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 98.5%;
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
}

.wp-caption p.wp-caption-text {
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 17px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 4px 5px;
}

/* Text meant only for screen readers. */
.screen-reader-text {
clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
position: absolute !important;
height: 1px;
width: 1px;
overflow: hidden;
}

.screen-reader-text:focus {
background-color: #f1f1f1;
border-radius: 3px;
box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
clip: auto !important;
color: #21759b;
display: block;
font-size: 14px;
font-size: 0.875rem;
font-weight: bold;
height: auto;
left: 5px;
line-height: normal;
padding: 15px 23px 14px;
text-decoration: none;
top: 5px;
width: auto;
z-index: 100000; /* Above WP toolbar. */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I'm not a web dev, how can I use the above to fix my issue?

Comment: That depends on many issues.  If you are not a developer, I have to assume you are using a pre-made theme from another author?  If so, I also have to assume there are rules in that theme's CSS file(s) to properly style the align___ classes.  You may simply need to apply an alignment choice to the image in the page editor.  This article should help if so.  http://webtrainingwheels.com/image-positioning-spacing-alignment-wordpress-problems/